# picking and saving date, time and location in android

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which some of the features include choosing the current location, date and time using google maps, date picker and time picker respectively. I want the above to be chosen and then shown in a blank space (plain text space) and finally be stored into the database. But I am unable to understand how to do it.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Can you create the UI? Do you know how to save the data to a database? Do you know how to update the UI with data?

Comment: yes...I can create the user interface but I only know how to save data ,into database, that are manually entered...

Comment: That only answers one of my 4 questions.

Comment: yes...I know how to update UI with data....but that too the ones which are entered manually...

Comment: I still do not understand what you need help with.

Comment: I want that the user selects his current location using google maps....this I can do....but then I also want that the location that he chose be saved into database...I can't do the latter

Comment: Is the database local to the phone or do you want to save it to a database on a server? For a local database, I suggest you read about how to use SQLite in an Android app. There are many online tutorials about it.